VPN parameter useragent and NetworkManager
After some changes on server or in local packages now during trial to connect vpn server I receive 404 error response. Preiously I was using configuration for NetworkManager under Gnome with success for 2 years. I already found a solution when debug connection with command line openconnect client.
It requires adding parameter --useragent=AnyConnect and connection is working fine
Now it's time to update NetworkManager. I didnt't found any field in gui to enter this parameter or add custom parameters to pass to openconnect.
I've found that config reflecting graphic form is located in:
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN 1.nmconnection
I'v added 'useragent=AnyConnect' line to [vpn] and even after restart of system (to reload configs) vpn connection window reports 404 still
How I should pass this parameter?
Here is [vpn] section from my config:
[vpn]
authtype=cert
autoconnect-flags=0
cacert=/etc/pki/tls/certs/Company_Root_CA.crt
certsigs-flags=0
cookie-flags=2
enable_csd_trojan=no
gateway=vpn.net.company.com/EE-Linux
gateway-flags=2
gwcert-flags=2
lasthost-flags=0
pem_passphrase_fsid=no
prevent_invalid_cert=no
protocol=anyconnect
resolve-flags=2
stoken_source=manual
useragent=AnyConnect
usercert=/home/user/keys/user.crt
userkey=/home/user/keys/user.key
xmlconfig-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect


You left us with guesswork about your configuration.
In case you're on Ubuntu 22.04, there's a known issue with OpenConnect, that passes "Open AnyConnect VPN Agent v$VERSION" as UserAgent by default. And there doesn't seem to be a way to configure this in the NetworkManager GUI before Ubuntu 24.04.
Someone on Reddit patched the binaries, which is a bit dirty but seemed to work for him (though not for me):
sed -i.bck 's/OpenConnect VPN Agent (NetworkManager)/AnyConnect-compatible OpenConnect VPN Agent /g' /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-auth-dialog

(Note: I modified the Reddit answer slightly to match the string that OpenConnect passes by default in newer versions)

Yes, my system is 22.04.
I tried this dirty patch but didn't work - there was no time to investigate why.
To continue my projects at work I use now openconnect commandline, but there is a big drawback - it doesn't activate global proxy setting so not everything works ok, e.g. apt is looking for some ipv6 addresses, in terminal I have to manually activate script to fetch proxy variables, in gui programs set proxy separatelly
There is already plan to migrate to 24.04.1 but I need to prepare backup, same time I will move to bigger disk etc.
Formatting disapeared even if in edit \n's visible

Thanks for the confirmation on your system; can you edit your  question to include the information you added in this answer, to aid those focusing on your question.

@AdamMierzwiak and while your at it and think that my answer is helpful for others, kindly mark it as "accepted".

@Uwe I'v apply your fix but didn;t make a difference in my setup.
Looking urgently for sollution I switched to connect with command line call with agent name passed by parameter. It is not optimal because network manager was applying proxy everywhere and switch on/off together with vpn. Later probably IT change something more and connection via NM was  facing another errors. My plan is to switch to Ubuntu 2024.4.1 where NM has field to input agent name

@AdamMierzwiak that fix suggested on Reddit also didn't work for me. On my older Ubuntu VM, I'll simply continue to live with the issue and either connect via CLI or log in via GUI on second attempt. Because for me, a second attempt after getting the 404 works. I heard from others that they don't get a second login prompt, however.

I remember also something like this that second trial was successful on my computer or my freinds
